# android ui design for an app help needed

Tags: android, user-interface, layout

One activity in my app looks like below picture. In the below picture ,can any one suggest that best way to implement view,

[view in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4uOw.png)
and when i click one of the options(filters in app) available on activity,
the view will be extended like below
[view after one of the option selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLG3N.png)

For this, i want to use a horizontal linear layout for  below options bar,
when one of the options clicked, i wanna use slide up functionality and views show and hide functionalities.

can any one suggest better design for this . thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think for most apps, all toolbars should stay in the same place throughout the execution of the app. When the toolbar item ("Veg & Non Veg") is clicked, the filter should appear above the toolbar instead of below it. You can still use the slide up function, just have the toolbar layout displayed above (higher z-index) the filter linear layout.

You should also standardize the sizes for the distances/times to each location, personally I think the [first one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q4uOw.png) looks better.

Other than that, I think your UI looks pretty good!

Comment: thank u for ur suggestion. i try to implement like that.